# Sorting a list based on the 2nd key

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I need help in sorting a list with 2 keys inside. For example, if I input "google" the output should be like this:

```
Letter: 'g', Frequency: 2
Letter: 'o', Frequency: 2
Letter: 'e', Frequency: 1
Letter: 'l', Frequency: 1
```

But instead, what I get is this:

```
Letter: 'e', Frequency: 1
Letter: 'g', Frequency: 2
Letter: 'l', Frequency: 1
Letter: 'o', Frequency: 2
```

Basically it just sorts the letters and not the frequency. What I wanted was for it to be sorted by Frequency first then by Letter. Here is my code snippet for the sorting part and a dictionary sample declaration:

```
adict = {'Letter':'a', 'Frequency':0}
bdict = {'Letter':'b', 'Frequency':0}
cdict = {'Letter':'c', 'Frequency':0}

def getKey(item):
    return item['Frequency']

finalArr = sorted(newArr, key = getKey)
```

I've tried the lambda sorting and the itemgetter but it still sorts the letter.

Here's the Frequency updating part (not the whole part just a sample):

```
for ex in range(0, len(temp)):
    if temp[count] == 'a': adict['Frequency']+=1
    elif temp[count] == 'b': bdict['Frequency']+=1
    elif temp[count] == 'c': cdict['Frequency']+=1
```

And here's if the Frequency is not 0 it will be assigned to a list:

```
if adict['Frequency'] != 0 : newArr.append(adict) 
if bdict['Frequency'] != 0 : newArr.append(bdict)
if cdict['Frequency'] != 0 : newArr.append(cdict)
```

Comment: all frequency having the same value, then how? Your example is incomplete, add the value of `newArr` var.

Comment: A list with two keys is a dict. Dict is an unsorted datatype. What is newArr in your code, is it a list of dicts? Need more code/better example.

Comment: I've updated my post Avinash and yes @kingledion newArr is basically a list of dicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a tuple from your key function:

```
def getKey(item):
    return (item['Frequency'], item['Letter'])
```

Answer (score 0):

For little functions you can use `lambda` functions. This will save you from clogged code.:

```
l = [
    {'Letter': 'o', 'Frequency': 2},
    {'Letter': 'e', 'Frequency': 1}]

print sorted(l, key=lambda x: [x['Frequency'], x['Letter']])
```

For descending order use `reverse`:

```
print sorted(l, key=lambda x: [x['Frequency'], x['Letter']], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the `Counter` class from the `collections` standard library, then the code is a little simpler:

```
from collections import Counter
string_input = 'google'
counter = Counter(string_input)
for letter, frequency in counter.most_common():
    print 'Letter: {!r}, Frequency: {}'.format(letter, frequency)
```

The only problem with this approach is the letters are not sorted, so the output might look something like this:

```
Letter: 'o', Frequency: 2
Letter: 'g', Frequency: 2
Letter: 'e', Frequency: 1
Letter: 'l', Frequency: 1
```